Chrome Extension - Resume execution after Refreshing the page, from refresh was triggered - How to
I have this chrome extension, its contentScript.js triggers a refresh while execution. When the page is refreshed, execution ceases and doesn't resume.
I want it to resume from where it caused the refresh page.
This causes the Refresh.
 const nextItem = selectedItem.nextElementSibling;
      if (nextItem) {
        nextItem.click();
      } else {
        console.log("Next item not found.");
        break;
      }
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));}

I want to resume execution from the very next line.
I just don't understand how to do it. I have tried different resources but no luck.
Please help me, I am really new to this.

When you click a link that navigates to a different URL, the old page is destroyed along with its content scripts. You can save the state in chrome.storage.session or use messaging with the background script, so that when the content script runs in the new page it can pick up from where it was.

I've tried to do this, but couldn't understand how to implement it exactly. Can you send a guide article or something.

I don't have a link, but I know such questions were asked more than once, so there should be examples around. Try using google search, not the built-in search here.
